# I don't understand why does my error message won't work

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new/inexperienced to c# and I am trying to write a bool method to validate if the user input in a windows form is empty, which returns as true or false, as well as change the `errorMessage` Variable to have new text if it returns false.

```
 public static bool IsPresent(string value)
 { 
     if (value == "")
     {
         errorMessage = "all textboxes and combo boxes must be filled";
         return false;
     }
     else
     {
         errorMessage = "";
         return true;
     }
}
```

I get **compile time error** on `errorMessage`, saying

> "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'".

I declared the `errorMessage` variable at the top of my file and made it public.
I have tried getting rid of the static aspect of the method, which does fix it, but causes more errors elsewhere in my code.
Do you know how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: why is `IsPresent` `static`?

Comment: Read up on what `static` means. You can think of static as "belonging to the class as a whole", while non-static mean "belonging to a specific instance of the class". So, if you are in a non-static method, you can access static members. However, if you are in a static method, you don't have a reference to a particular class instance, so you can't access static members. As comments on your question: you really should have shown the declaration of `errorMessage` and you should have said where the error message occurs. Finally, `value` is a C# keyword, using it is benign here, but...

Comment: `IsPresent` is `static` and `errorMessage` is not. you can't use a `non-static` object inside a `static` method or class. either both `static` or `non-static`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare public static field and do it like this of course:

```
static class Helper
{
    public static string errorMessage;

    public static bool IsPresent(string value)
    {
        if (value == "")
        {
            errorMessage = "all textboxes and combo boxes must be filled";
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            errorMessage = "";
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

But this's got a few problems, one of them is that errorMessage can be now modified by some foreign class, so it should be changed to something else, for example:

```
private static string errorMessage;

public static string GetMessageCopy()
{
    return errorMessage;
}
```

You can change this to property, which does the same thing, but it's easier to read:

```
public static string ErrorMessage { get; private set; } // property should always start with a big letter
```

Now only Helper class can modify ErrorMessage, but everyone can read it.

Next problem is that name of your parameter "value" is a C# keyword, which is used for different things, so please, think of renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variable first inside the static function. If you have declared it outside the method's scope I recommend removing the static keyword so it should look like this:

```cs
string errorMessage;
bool IsPresent(string value)
{
    if (value == "")
     {
          errorMessage = "all textboxes and combo boxes must be filled";
          return false;
     }
     else
     {
         errorMessage = "all textboxes and combo boxes must be filled";
         return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on static. You could start with [static (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).

However, there are solutions that don't require a member variable (what you called *at the top of my file*) and avoid the static/non-static issue. For example, let's consider this solution:

```
(bool IsValid, string? ErrorMessage) IsPresent(string? s)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
     {
          return(IsValid: false, ErrorMessage: "All textboxes and combo boxes must be filled");
     }
     else
     {
         return(IsValid: true, ErrorMessage: null);
     }
}
```

Notes:

1. Please note I used `string.IsNullOrEmpty` rather than `== ""`. You may want to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to make the requirement even stronger.
2. You may need to change `(bool IsValid, string? ErrorMessage) IsPresent(string? s)` to `(bool IsValid, string ErrorMessage) IsPresent(string s)` if you're not using a fresh version of .NET.

If we think about it a bit more we can notice that IsValid is redundant.  Checking if the error is return is enough:

```
string? CheckValid(string? s)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
     {
          return "All textboxes and combo boxes must be filled";
     }

     //if ( ... some other requirement )
     //{
     //     return "Some error";
     //}

     return null;
}
```